# Dont't show the notification when the user is logout

Tags: android

I am receiving notification even after logout from the app. Which method is called ? Or what can I do so that I will not receive notification when I logout. Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code for what you tried?

Comment: Unregister your token from your server

Comment: have you keep a bit of user that tells you if user is login or logout ?

Comment: I don't know app name. But almost every apps have setting page. You can find it easily.
Move to setting page. Then you can find notification control switch.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would say, on logout there should be an API call which deletes that device's token entry from the server.